# Authentication issues when hosting static site on DropBox

Tags: web-hosting, authentication

I am trying to host my *static* website on Dropbox and forward my domain to the public link of `index.html` of my site; I'm following the last tip from [this post](http://www.maketecheasier.com/4-ways-to-host-your-website-on-dropbox/).

I have two problems with this approach:

1. In the address bar I see the following: [image]. What does this yellow triangle means? Can I solve this?
2. Also in the address bar, at the other end, I see the following: [image] gray shield. When the cursor hovers over the shield it says "This page includes script from unauthenticated sources". How can I solve this? Let me point that the same site was hosted on my uni's server and there was no problem...

The above description is relevant when I load the site in Chrome. In Safari I get an annoying popup that there are scripts that have to be enabled. I will be happy to provide further details if needed.

For the sake of reference, you can see the problem on your own: [www.dr-atariah.com](http://www.dr-atariah.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yellow triangle says that some parts of the webpage, such as CSS and JavaScript for example, are not served using `https://`. Yet the page which you are viewing is using `https://` and is secure.

Both icons are telling you that.

**Update 1**

If you click on the icons, it will tell you the details regarding it.

It is going to say something along the lines that the page `is` secure, but there is some element(s) of the page that is not secure.

Comment: "are not served"? But I can see the styling generated by the CSS and if I enable it then the scripts run as well... I don't understand. Can I somehow workaround it?

Comment: I used that as an example for what could not be served with HTTPS on the webpage. You can just ignore it in all reality.